# MongoDB cannot get all data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

### Problem

I want to fetch all records from my MongoDB collection which have the username or other name in the `from or to` fields. It is a chat application. I want to fetch all the chats between the user and the other user. It is a schema in a way that when user sends a message their username will get saved in `from` section, and when they recieve it, their username will get saved in the `to` section. This is also the same way for the other User.

Please refer to this below:

### On using || in syntax

```
getMessages: async(_, { name }, context) => {
    const user = checkAuth(context);

    if(!user) throw new AuthenticationError('Not logged in');
    
    const otherUser = await User.findOne({username: name})

    if (!otherUser) throw new UserInputError('User Input Error');

    const messages = await Chat.find({        
        from: otherUser.username || user.username,
        to: user.username || otherUser.username
    }).sort({createdAt: -1})
            
    return messages
}
```

#### Output

[image: On || Operator]

### On using && Operator

```
getMessages: async(_, { name }, context) => {
    const user = checkAuth(context);

    if (!user) throw new AuthenticationError('Not logged in');

    const otherUser = await User.findOne({username: name})

    if (!otherUser) throw new UserInputError('User Input Error');

    const messages = await Chat.find({      // Here is the change
        from: otherUser.username && user.username,
        to: user.username && otherUser.username
   }).sort({createdAt: -1})
            
   return messages
}
```

#### Output

[image: on && operator]

### Objective

I want to get all records between the given user in the `name` argument and the logged in user. For example between Jahad and Mazino.

Comment: Please don't paste images, provide code and error as formatted text: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with the `$or` operator, like:

```
const messages = await Chat.find({        
    from: {$or: [otherUser.username, user.username]},
    to: {$or: [otherUser.username, user.username]}
}).sort({createdAt: -1})
```

Comment: It gives me the error ```cannot use $or with String```.. So I just removed the $or operator and it worked. Thank you!